# Upload дополнительных файлов Google Play

Tags: java, android-studio, google-play

Я сделал аудиокнигу, и она весит 250 мб. Лимит на Google Play 100 мб. Я знаю, что Google Play дает возможность загрузить дополнительные файлы отдельно от самой программы. Помогите, пожалуйста, как мне загрузить отдельно мои 113 mp3 файлов и как как это указать в самом коде приложения? СПАСИБО!

Comment: возможно эта ссылка вам поможет  https://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html

Comment: @Kirill Stoianov Я тут был ... Я не смог решить проблему оттуда... (